# DataTable jquery selectors not firing

Tags: javascript, datatables

I have following code to handle clicks on row or individual cells.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var JSON_URL = '{% url "technician_activity" %}';
    var oTable = $('#technician_activity').dataTable( {
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": JSON_URL ,
        "jQueryUI":       true
    } );
    alert("Without this alert selectors don't work? oTable = " + oTable);
    oTable.$('tr').click( function () {
       var data = oTable.fnGetData( this );
       alert("Column " + data);
    });
    oTable.$('td').click( function () {
       var data = oTable.fnGetData( this );
       alert("Cell " + data);
    });

});
```

One thing that puzzels me is without the first alert statement

```
alert("Without this alert selectors don't work? oTable = " + oTable);
```

selectors for tr and td don't work this is very puzzling to me -- what is the difference that this alert() is making?

Comment: I don't have the answer but I think the `alert` is giving some time needed to fetch the data from the server

Comment: Nope I don't thik that is the case, I waited for all the data rows ( 5 of them total! ) to be fetched. Then clicked on row/column and the selector as shown in code are not working without that initial alert()...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am now using code as suggested here - http://www.datatables.net/examples/server_side/select_rows.html

But it still remains question as to why the in code I initially posted, with first alert() statement things work but they don't work when that alert statement is absent....

Just for curiosity sake would like to understand whats going on there in case someone has ideas.

Comment: Further more someone on DataTable forum provided explanation of why things work with alert() and not without it - http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/comment/67161#Comment_67161